# How to confirm datagram packet source address?

Tags: java, udp, datagram

I've written a Java RDT client/server program that exchanges datagram packets to correct packet corruption and loss. The final bit of code I added requires that I compare each packet's source address to the address of the original packet.

```
   //global
    InetAddress originalSender;

    //C'tor
    originalSender = null;

        ...


//primary method
    public byte[] rdt_receive() throws IOException
        { 
            while (true) {

                DatagramPacket recPacket = new DatagramPacket(new byte [PACKET_SIZE], PACKET_SIZE);
                dgSock.receive(recPacket);

                if (originalSender == null) {
                    System.out.println("Address is set!\n");
                    originalSender = recPacket.getAddress();
                }

                if( originalSender != recPacket.getAddress() ) {

                    System.out.println("Wrong sender!");
                    sendAck((short) (expectedSequence == 0 ? 1 : 0), recPacket.getSocketAddress());
                    continue;
                } 
    // continue method...
```

`"Address is set"` is never printed so `if(originalSender == null)`never returns true, even for the first packet. I've also tried `SocketAddress` and `.getSocketAddress()` to no avail. Help is much appreciated.

EDIT:
`"Wrong sender"` is printed in an infinite loop.  I'm running both client and server on the same computer and the first received packet is successfully written to a file.  The program works before adding the block of if statements, correctly sending a text file and closing both client and server.

Are `InetAddress`/`SocketAddress` automatically assigned by the OS if set to null?

Comment: Are you sure you're receiving anything at all? Put a printout after '.receive()'

Comment: Thanks yes it does receive. I've edited the post.

Comment: Why are you printing 'address is set' when it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare InetAddresses with ==. You need to call equals().

But you don't need this. Just connect() the socket to the original sender when you get the first packet. Then UDP will do the filtering for you.

Comment: Good to know, that worked.  Do know the reason for implementing InetAddress comparisons directly in a method rather than with an operator? Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's the same for String and every other class in Java. Nothing special about InetAddress. There are no overloads of the == operator.

Comment: Isn't "==" just checking pointer equivalence? I.e. are these two variables pointing to the same object?